# Code calling reverse function does not compile on either g++ or clang++ on Ubuntu 18, but mysteriously works on mac osx

Tags: c++, stl-algorithm

On Mac OSX, clang version 7.0.2 the code compiles.
On Ubuntu clang version 7.0.0 it does not. Is there really a difference in some default library, this seems weird?

MWE:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string A = "abc";
    reverse(A.begin(), A.end());
}
```

Is one really bringing in algorithm somehow, but different between the two versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes default libraries vary on different systems with different compilers. If you use a certain function, include the respective header. On your Mac the reverse function seems to be include somewhere deep in the string header.
Use `#include <algorithm>` and it should work on the other systems too.

Comment: @Dov Well, the system makes the difference. It's just good practice to include what you need, because you can't rely on the headers implicitly including other functions, that are not explicitly part of the header.

Comment: I don't think that #including <algorithm> isn't going to change the result here.

Comment: @MarshallClow I'm sorry. Do you mean, it is going to change the result, or not? Your sentence is not so clear. By adding `#include <algorithm>` you ensure, that the preprocessor looks up the function in that header (where it is declared), so i am pretty confident, about it changing the result.

Comment: I agree; my comment wasn't clear. However, I believe that #including <algorithm> will NOT change the result.

Answer (score 1):

The default standard library on Mac OS is libc++.
The default standard library on Ubuntu is libstdc++.

You can try on Ubuntu by passing `-stdlib=libc++` to the compiler, and see what happens.

The difference is (I suspect, but do not know for sure) that on libc++ `string::iterator` is a type in namespace std, so ADL lookup occurs, but in libstdc++ the iterators are just `char *`, and since they don't live in namespace std, no lookup in that namespace occurs.